# Find the inequalities that represents a region

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]
Let $y_1 = 2x - \frac{1}{8} x^2$
Then $y_1$ meets the line $l_2$ at $x=0 , x= 12$
And meets the line $l_1$ At $x= 16$
Then the inequalities are 
$$y1< = l_2 , 12< = x < 16 $$ ?
Is this answer matching the required ?

Comment: Is this question part of an ongoing examination?  If not, could you reference the package from where you got this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find the inequalities that represent the region between $l_1$ and $C$, then just add another restriction.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $$2x-\frac{1}{8}x^2 <2x $$ with the condition $$12< x< 16$$ ? @John Joy

Comment: Yes, almost, but don't forget to include $y$ in the inequation. $2x - \frac{1}{8}x^2 < y < 2x$